# A deduction in 1st course of complex analysis if a particular series is given absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am trying assignment problems in complex analysis and I couldn't deduce the reasoning behind a particular Statement.

> Suppose f is holomorphic in an open neighborhood of $z_{0} $ $\epsilon $
> $\mathbb{C} $. Given that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^{n} (z_{0})  $ converges absolutely, then how can we conclude that f can be extended to an entire function?

I know of a result that uniform convergence on compact sets implies analyticity. By M-test (Uniform convergence ) I can deduce that f is uniformly convergent locallyand  on compact intervel it is entire.

But, can it be extended on whole of $\mathbb{C} $ ? I think it cannot be as convergence is not uniform everywhere. Am I right in my reasoning?

Comment: note: Not $z_0\in \mathbb C$ is better than $z_0\epsilon \mathbb C,$

Comment: @zhw can you please tell how to write the former?

Comment: \in \mathbb C with dollar signs around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence of $\sum f^{(n)}(z_0)$ implies that $f^{(n)}(z_0) \to 0$. In particular this implies boundedness of $(f^{(n)}(z_0))$ and this is enough to conclude that $\frac {\sum f^{(n)}(z_0)} {n!} (z-z_0)^{n}$ converges for every complex number $z$. This series has radius of convergence $\infty$ and its sum is an entire function.